# ¿Cómo imprimir una dirección de memoria en ADA?

Tags: punteros, manejo-de-memoria, ada

estoy empezando a programar en ADA y ahora mismo estoy con el tema de los punteros y registros de memorias. Quiero imprimir la dirección de memoria a la que apunta un puntero de una variable, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
package print renames Ada.Text_IO;
procedure punteros is
  U: aliased Integer;
begin
  U := 5; 
  P := U'Access;
  print.Put_Line("La dirección de memoria es: " & Integer'Value(P);
end punteros;
```

Pero salta un error, alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?
Muchas gracias de antemano